# How do I insert an element or component in an array at a specific index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, split

I have an array with 25 items (Will increase), and I want to split it into chunks of 10 each. After the 1st chunk, I want to insert an image and a component after the 2nd chunk of 10. Sharing the code I have written so far.

```
const DESKTOP_SPLIT = 10;

  handleSplit = () => {
    const { listings } = this.props;
    let finalArr = [[]];
    let currentArr = 0;
    const myArray = [...listings];
    

    for (let i = 0; i < listings.length; i++) {
      if (i % DESKTOP_SPLIT === 0) {
        currentArr += 1;
        
        if (!finalArr[currentArr]) {
          finalArr[currentArr] = [];
        }
      }
      finalArr[currentArr].push(i);
    }
    return finalArr;
  };

Expected output:

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [<SomeComponent />],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [Some image],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, ...]
]
```

In the code above the myArray variable contains the array I want to split. How do I go forward with this and insert an element/component dynamically after every 10th element in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I've understood, but you could probably use the [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to achieve what you're after. Here's some code that will insert the string `'SPLICE'` after every second element in the array:

```js
const SPLICE_AFTER = 2;
const data = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'];

const result = [...data];

for (let i = result.length - (result.length % SPLICE_AFTER); i > 0; i -= SPLICE_AFTER) {
  result.splice(i, 0, 'SPLICE');
}

// Produces: ["One", "Two", "SPLICE", "Three", "Four", "SPLICE", "Five"]
console.log(result);
```

Note that you have to do this from the back to the front since the array grows after each time you do an insert.

---

**Edit**: Thanks for clarifying with the comment - I had misunderstood the splitting part you were referring to. You can use the [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method instead to achieve what you're after:

```js
const CHUNK_SIZE = 2;
const data = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'];

// This will be a two-dimensional array
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += CHUNK_SIZE) {
  const chunk = data.slice(i, i + CHUNK_SIZE);
  chunk.push("SPLICE");
  result.push(chunk);
}

// Produces: [
//   ['One', 'Two', 'CHUNK'], 
//   ['Three', 'Four', 'CHUNK'], 
//   ['Five', 'CHUNK']
// ]
console.log(result);
```

[Here it is running at CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-morning-nebpd?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: I think this does the splitting but will it also help me add elements to the array dynamically? Similar to 'SPLICE' being inserted I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I think I couldn't specify the problem, well enough. What I want the output to be is something like this:

 ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'], 
 [<MyComponent/>],
 ['Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten'], 
[<img src='' alt"" />]

Is this possible?

Comment: I obviously don't understand your full requirements, but the code above should solve the core of the problem for you. Based on what I know, I'd probably do something like this - https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-perlman-7lxqt?file=/src/Chunks.js